# windows shell scripting through java

Tags: java, winapi

i am designing a desktop application like nero for removable media storage that also includes features of copyfast. i want to add an option of my own choice in the windows explorer right click menu. how can i do that? am i proceeding in the right direction?

Comment: you will need to write a platform dependent plugin for explorer. this cannot be done in java. take a look at http://izpack.org/ for OS dep installation

Answer (score 0):

What does your question has to do with shell scripting?

You can get the functionality with c sharp easily:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/appendmenu.aspx

But take a look other peoples work where the embed the windows context menu within a java app:

_ttp://timealias.bplaced.net/ContextMenuPlugin/ (can only post only link; need more rep)